# Interactive Brokers - TWS API - Minimum Price Increment

Tags: python, price, interactive-brokers, tws

I am trying to create a TWS API script which will place an order in the STK market. I found out that there are various market rules, which dictate minimum price increment. I queried the system to find out the `marketRuleIds`, but I cannot figure out how to interpret the results from `reqMarketRule`, e.g. the market rule ID `557` provides following results:

```
Price Increment. LowEdge: 0.000000, Increment: 0.000100
Price Increment. LowEdge: 1.000000, Increment: 0.010000
```

The market rule ID 26 provides following results:

```
Price Increment. LowEdge: 0.000000, Increment: 0.010000
```

And the market rule ID 1916 provides following results:

```
Price Increment. LowEdge: 0.000000, Increment: 0.000001
Price Increment. LowEdge: 0.001000, Increment: 0.000002
Price Increment. LowEdge: 0.002000, Increment: 0.000005
Price Increment. LowEdge: 0.005000, Increment: 0.000010
Price Increment. LowEdge: 0.010000, Increment: 0.000020
Price Increment. LowEdge: 0.020000, Increment: 0.000050
Price Increment. LowEdge: 0.050000, Increment: 0.000100
Price Increment. LowEdge: 0.100000, Increment: 0.000200
Price Increment. LowEdge: 0.200000, Increment: 0.000500
Price Increment. LowEdge: 0.500000, Increment: 0.001000
Price Increment. LowEdge: 1.000000, Increment: 0.002000
Price Increment. LowEdge: 2.000000, Increment: 0.005000
Price Increment. LowEdge: 5.000000, Increment: 0.010000
Price Increment. LowEdge: 10.000000, Increment: 0.020000
Price Increment. LowEdge: 20.000000, Increment: 0.050000
Price Increment. LowEdge: 50.000000, Increment: 0.100000
Price Increment. LowEdge: 100.000000, Increment: 0.200000
Price Increment. LowEdge: 200.000000, Increment: 0.500000
Price Increment. LowEdge: 500.000000, Increment: 1.000000
```

When I tried to place a trade for a STK with the market rule `1916` within the TWS application, I could see that the increment is 0.50 GBP, but I am not sure how to track it back to the above output.

Can you please help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer from Reddit comment on the same question. Thank you, major_domo for your help!

Excerpt from the answer provided:
"

```
Price Increment. LowEdge: 100.000000, Increment: 0.200000
Price Increment. LowEdge: 200.000000, Increment: 0.500000
Price Increment. LowEdge: 500.000000, Increment: 1.000000
```

or prices above 100, the minimum increment is 0.2; for prices above 200, the minimum increment is 0.5; for prices above 500, it is 1.

I assume the current price is between 200 and 500 if TWS shows the increment is 0.5.
"

Comment: Are those pence or pounds?  There is a price magnifier field that's supposed to be used but IIRC it's only a factor in the UK.  I don't use it.

Comment: Found the post. BTW, lots of info in that thread.  https://groups.io/g/twsapi/message/45468

Comment: The price in the comment is pounds, but it is a good point, I guess each security type needs to be checked explicitly

Answer (score 1):

If you want to determine the price increment, you can get the information from contract details.  The minTick field provides you with the minimum price increment for the contract.  For example, on the contract 'QQQ', the minTick is 0.01, meaning you can submit orders that are in U.S. dollars, 1 penny increments.  An order with something that has more than 2 digits to the right of the decimal point will fail.

Comment: Hm, for US it seems OK, as it shows like you said, but e.g. for UK stock, e.g. `ASCL` trading at `LSE` with `GBP`, the `minTick` was `1e-06` or `0.000001`. When I tried to place an bracket order with take profit of `432.65` the system gave an error:

`ERROR 21 110 The price does not conform to the minimum price variation for this contract.`

When I look at TWS, I can see that the increments are round integers, no decimals for this stock.

Any advice?

Comment: I'm baffled by it also.  When I look at ASCL using the IB TWS software, it's priced in $0.20 increments.  I don't have experience trading non-US contracts with the API.  I wonder if it has something to do with the currency conversion; i.e., the currency associated with the contract is GBP and the minTick is also in GBP.